# Relative Leopoldt defect

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Let F be a totally real number field such that the Leopoldt conjecture holds at a prime number $p$ and $M$ be a quadratic totally real extension of $F$.

Is there a bound of the Leopoldt defect of $M$ ?

Comment: $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$? $\ \ \ $

Comment: We assume that F is finite over $\mathbb{Q}$ and I know that a theorem of waldschmidt implies that the leopoldt defect of $M$ is $[M:\mathbb{Q}]/2$, but I ask if there is a better bound or if Leopoldt conjecture holds for this case.

Comment: I think $[M:\mathbf{Q}]/2$ *is* $[F:\mathbf{Q}]$ and my comment was supposed to mean that this is a bound (my comment is an answer) and unless I'm mistaken the proof is trivial: the unit rank goes up by $[F:\mathbf{Q}]$ and so now you just imagine that the topological closure doesn't go up at all. I don't see why Leopoldt should hold for $M$ if it holds for $F$. It's known to hold for $F/\mathbf{Q}$ abelian but as far as I know it's not known for quadratic extensions of abelian extensions.

Comment: In my question I take number fields with some assumptions in the aim to know if there is a better bound than the result of Waldshmidt in this case, and I know that Leopoldt conjecture holds for abelian extensions and cyclic extension of a quadratic complex extension (Baker-Brumer)

Comment: I want to stress that the result you have referred to several times as "a result of Waldschmidt" is in this case trivially true -- just look at how the rank can change. Because it's trivial, perhaps Waldschmidt's *methods* give you something better in this case?

Comment: The rank of the global units of $M$ is $[M:\mathbb{Q}]-1$ and the rank of the product of the local units of $M$ is $[M:\mathbb{Q}]$, hence the Leopoldt defect of $M$ is less than than $[M:\mathbb{Q}]$, but the result of Walshmidt is more precise. When you said the unit rank goes up by ... you speak about local or global ? and the both case your answer is wrong.

Comment: You assume that Leopoldt is true for $F$! So the rank of the global units (from $F$ to $M$) goes up by $[F:\mathbf{Q}]=([M:\mathbf{Q}]-1)-([F:\mathbf{Q}]-1)$, and the rank of the topological closure in the local units might not change (it might go up by 0), so this instantly gives $[F:\mathbf{Q}]-0=[F:\mathbf{Q}]$ as a bound for the defect in this situation without any Waldschmidt. I don't know Waldschmidt's techniques but perhaps they might do better in this case.